# How much damage for Eternal Confidence via an Opportune Riposte?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, swashbuckler

[Swashbuckler's](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=15) Eternal Confidence (scroll to bottom of prior link) gives the [Confident Finisher](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=550) failure effect to [Opportune Ripostes](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=551). But how much of the Precise Strike damage is done? Confident Finisher's failure effect is:

> **Failure** You deal half your precise strike damage to the target. This damage type is that of the weapon or unarmed attack you used for the Strike.

So normally, if one is using Confident Finisher, they would deal the Xd6 damage from Precise Strike (e.g. 6d6 / 2 at the level you get Eternal Confidence) on a failure. However, I'm not sure how much an Opportune Riposte would do here - it itself is not a finisher, so I'd assume that it does half of the Xd6 value (e.g. 6/2 = 3), but it is *inheriting* the effects of a finisher. Does that make it qualify for the Xd6 value instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Half Precise Strike damage

Eternal Confidence only gives Opportune Riposte the *Failure effect* of Confident Finisher

> When you Strike as part of a finisher or Opportune Riposte, you can give the Strike the failure effect from the Confident Finisher action, including the increase from Precise Finisher if you have that feat.

As you noted, the Failure effect is half of Precise Strike's damage. It does not increase damage done by a successful Riposte, and it does not increase the damage on the Failure effect.

If you're still unsure, note the portion "including the increase from Precise Finisher if you have that feat." [Precise Finisher](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1536) alters the Failure effect to be full Precise Strike damage. If you have Precise Finisher, your Opportune Ripostes would also gain this benefit; it takes a Feat to accomplish the other interpretation you present.